# Semantic versioning in npm

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

I am reading [this npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning) about semantic versioning.

I have seen that this syntax is used to tell npm what packages to install.

> Patch releases: 1.0 or 1.0.x or ~1.0.4

> Minor releases: 1 or 1.x or ^1.0.4

> Major releases: * or x

So my question is: If I set the semver of a package as `*1.9.0`, can it install any version of the package? And since major versions have breaking changes when is this syntax used?

Comment: You can try out specs against packages here: https://semver.npmjs.com/. I think you're looking for `>=1.9.0`.

Comment: I am just confused by what *1.9.0 means. Does it mean I can install any major version?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything.

Comment: so `*1.9.0` will just import version `1.9.0` and nothing else?

Comment: Please use the site above to see exactly what that would match for the package you're trying to install.

Comment: Thank you for being patient with me. I have seen the site. I now understand.